# Implement windows authentication in asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am a beginner in mvc and right now i have a web application using sql server 2008. This particular application is expected to authenticated the users based on the windows login and display their respective pages. I have come across many articles that ask to set something in the asp.net web site administrator tool. etc but i have no idea how to do them. Is there any tutorial which has a step by step process of implementing this.

Again, it would be helpful if there is information on how the application can authenticate the users based on their windows login and display their pages.

Thanks!

Comment: did you try the INTRAnet project MVC3 template? it should have everything in it that's required to work with windows authentication.

Comment: No i have developed a internet application. I have done the total application other than implementing the roles. How long would you think it would take to re-create the intranet project ? Will that help ?

Answer (score 0):

If your project isn't large, you could recreate it as an intranet app, and just copy over the code files.

Otherwise, you could create a separate intranet app with windows auth and copy values over from it's `web.config`.

In your `<system.web>`, you'd need stuff like the following:

```
    <authentication mode="Windows" />

    <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>

    <identity impersonate="true" />

    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider">
        <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
        </providers>
    </roleManager>
```

In fact, start by adding the above, and see how you go.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows authentication

make the connection string as follows,

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="MyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.My.csdl|res://*/Model.My.ssdl|res://*/Model.My.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=MyServer;initial catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
```

and add

```
<system.web>
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
<identity impersonate="true" userName="Your pc name" password="Your password"/></system.web>
```

Thats all..:)